# Homestead run command as root

Tags: shell-script, sudo, vagrant

Over my Homestead configuration, I try to make my `after.sh` script to auto-configure xdebug so over a box update or re-creation to be able to enfroce my configuration for it without the need to redo it manually all over the time.

The script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Configuring Xdebug"
ip=$(netstat -rn | grep "^0.0.0.0 " | cut -d " " -f10)
xdebug_config="/etc/php/$(php -v | head -n 1 | awk '{print $2}'|cut -c 1-3)/mods-available/xdebug.ini"

echo "IP for the xdebug to connect back: ${ip}"
echo "Xdebug Configuration path: ${xdebug_config}"
echo "Port for the Xdebug to connect back: ${XDEBUG_PORT}"
echo "Optimize for ${IDE} ide"
first_line=$(head -n1 ${xdebug_config})

if [ $IDE=='atom' ]; then
  echo "Configuring xdebug for ATOM ide"
  sudo cat <<EOL >${xdebug_config}
${first_line}
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_host=${ip}
xdebug.remote_port = ${XDEBUG_PORT}
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 1000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_autostart=true
xdebug.remote_log=xdebug.log
EOL
fi
```

And my `Homestead.yml` is as follows:

```
ip: 192.168.10.10
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox
authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
timeout: 120

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa
folders:
    -
        map: /home/pcmagas/Kwdikas/php/apps/ellakcy_member_app/
        to: /home/vagrant/code
sites:
    -
        map: homestead.test
        to: /home/vagrant/code/web
        type: symfony

databases:
    - homestead
    - homestead-test

variables:
  - key: database_host
    value: 127.0.0.1
  - key: database_port
    value: 3306
  - key: database_name
    value: homestead
  - key: database_user
    value: homestead
  - key: database_password
    value: secret
  - key: smtp_host
    value: localhost
  - key: smtp_port
    value: 1025
  - key: smtp_user
    value: no-reply@example.com
  - key: IDE
    value: atom
  - key: XDEBUG_PORT
    value: 9091

name: ellakcy-member-app
hostname: ellakcy-member-app
```

I have setup the following extra enviromental variables:

```
  - key: IDE
    value: atom
  - key: XDEBUG_PORT
    value: 9091
```

So I can offer a fine-grained configuration for the xdebug.

But when I run `vagrant provision` Iget the following error (in order to save space I did nbot put the whole output):

> ellakcy-member-app: /tmp/vagrant-shell: 37: /tmp/vagrant-shell: cannot create /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/xdebug.ini: Permission denied

That is caused by he command:

```
sudo cat <<EOL >${xdebug_config}
${first_line}
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_host=${ip}
xdebug.remote_port = ${XDEBUG_PORT}
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 1000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_autostart=true
xdebug.remote_log=xdebug.log
EOL
```

So I want to know how I can auto-configure settings for Homestead Vagrant box? (for examplethe xdebug config one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option for now it to run the whole script as root. By changing the following option to the `Vagrantfile`:

```
    config.vm.provision "shell", path: afterScriptPath, privileged: **false**, keep_color: true
```

To

```
    config.vm.provision "shell", path: afterScriptPath, privileged: **true**, keep_color: true
```

But it won't be able to read the enviromental varialbed from `Homestead.yml`.